# Loading files in default Internet browser programmatically

Tags: c#, winforms

I used this to load a file (html_file.html) from `Resources`

```
//string myFile = "C:\\Users\\...\\Resources\\html_file.html";      // this works
var myFile = Path.GetFullPath("html_file.html");            // this doesn't works

//myFile = myFile.ToString();
//myFile = myFile.Replace(@"\", @"\\");
//MessageBox.Show(myFile);  

try
{
    Process.Start(myFile);
}
catch (Win32Exception noBrowser)
{
    if (noBrowser.ErrorCode == -2147467259)
        MessageBox.Show(noBrowser.Message);
}
catch (System.Exception other)
{
    MessageBox.Show(other.Message);
}
```

Can someone tell me what's wrong?

EDIT : This works

`Build Action = Embedded Resource` and `Copy to Output Directory = Copy always`

```
string myFile = @".\Resources\html_file.html";
```

but I still need to have the path `Resources` with the file. Is there any way to have the 'html_file' inside my `.EXE` file?

Comment: Internet Explorer doesn't know how to read embedded resources from your executable.  You'll need to save your resource to disk.  Or perhaps better to not bother putting it in a resource in the first place since it doesn't do you much good.

Comment: @HansPassant: His Resource version is working, not the other way around.

Answer (score 4):

Quite obviously it cannot find the file in the current directory. Make sure the following are correct:

- The file is included in your project and its `Copy to Output Directory` property is set to `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`.
- Use `Application.StartupPath` to make sure you are pointing to correct directory, so the first line would become:

Code:

```
var myFile = Path.Combine(Application.StartupPath, "html_file.html");
```

Comment: it says that can't find the file... What's the correct `Build Action` property in this case?

Comment: `Copy if newer` should work. Make sure you are spelling the file name correctly. Also see if your file is located in project root or in a subfolder and change your path accordingly. I can't see any other reason for it to fail.

Comment: @mafap: Your problem has two parts now. First, you can of course put your html file "inside" your exe file by making it a resource, but the problem is that Internet Explorer or any other application cannot read that file from within the memory of your application. So end of the day, you'll have to write it to disk (in a temporary location) and then pass that path to Internet Explorer to open that file. My way or the highway!

Comment: The file is copied to Resources path, so it was missing `..."Resources\\html_file.html"`

Answer (score 1):

In the first method you specify the exact path to your file.
In the second one you ask the framework to create a fullpath.
The framework need to start from somewhere and it choose to start from your current directory but the file is not present there